# Database connection from front end

Tags: sql-server, secure-coding

I want to know why calling a database from the front end is considered a bad practice for security.

It is really so bad as to justify building an application layer with all its drawbacks: costs, performance, development time?

[image]

Comment: It is expected to do some basic research before you post a question here. Please read http://security.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: With _front-end_, you're referring to some sort of a _thin client_ in a _multi-tier_ environment, is that correct?

Comment: Given all the answers that start with "I'm not sure what you mean", I think some clarification from you would help.  "Front end" means a lot of different things to a lot of different people.  Your picture perhaps makes it clear, but I don't think anyone would consider web servers to be part of the "Front End".

Comment: your demarcation of where front-end is ... is wrong!  Front-end is just the `client` in your illustration.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unclear on what you mean by "front end" but if you are talking about somehow firing database commands directly from the client side of a web application this would be very bad.

Any client side javascript you have can be easily modified or circumvented entirely, meaning that any command you execute from the client side could be modified to do whatever a malicious user wants.  For example they could change your command from: `SELECT * FROM Products` to `DELETE Products`

In addition to that, it is a bad idea to have your database server accessible from the internet.  Typically you want to have a web server that is accessible from the internet and then your database server would be available to the web server.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/oy72dp96f/lan.jpg

Answer (score 2):

A database connection will let the user do pretty much anything he likes to the database, provided he has the access rights. Open a connection straight to the Internet, and the only thing keeping any user from admin account access is the secrecy of the password of the admin account. For the most part, you won't see a database system built with this sort of access in mind, so you won't see protections on the database itself that are crafted for this usage.

Given admin access, and connectivity, a hacker can:

- delete the database entirely
- rewrite the schema of the database
- resize the database, consuming more machine resources than you intended
- change the data in the database

So.. the return question is - what's the purpose of the database, and how much does it's integrity matter? If this is a test database for a student project, you may care more about the machine itself than the database. But in most applications, the information in the database and its validity, availability and reliability are the heart of the system. Lose that, or lose your trust in it and in many cases, you no longer have a functioning business.

Speaking as a web developer, though, the biggest driver to having a web app is still not security - it's functionality. People don't tend to think in SQL - so you need an interface that lets a less technical user view and manipulate data in a way that the user can comprehend. Once you admit, even in one case, that you need a web server or app server to render the data into a user-readable page - then you've bitten off the need for the bigger costs of staging the application server. And once you've invested time and energy in developing forms or other data input mechanisms that the average user can use, you've invested enough in the site overall, that doing it correctly - with solid security practices - is a wise investment not only to protect your data, but to protect the value of the investment in building the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean.  Separation in to layers like application and business logic and data access is not so much about security as it is about maintainability.  It's done to make the code useable and be able to do things like change the database you use without having to fully rewrite the application.

It does also make security easier as you can secure the DAL to ensure that SQL calls can't be abused, but the same thing can still be done with a little more effort even if your code is completely flat.

So your initial premise that it is a bad security practice isn't exactly correct, it's just a bad programming practice in general.  The fact that it makes security more difficult to implement well is just a secondary effect of the bad general design.

Comment: The front end code (JavaScript) is visible to the world.one just can't put the db access credentials in the front end code

Comment: no! front-end isn't javascript! frontend are the servers that host the ui of the application and sometime also the business logic and data logic

Comment: @MayankSharma - that's the client side.  In my experience, front end generally refers to the logic that actually renders the HTML where as the back end is the "brains" of the site.  The typical pattern is for a front end to request data from the back end via calls that can be swapped out to make it run off of any DB platform.  So DB + DB layer is backend, HTML generation is front end and business logic can live in either, depending on approach.

Comment: @Shurmajee - putting the db access credentials (login + password) in the front end code would certainly  be problematic, but you could connect from front end js while the login and password are entered by the user. If the front end code ends up in the wrong hands, it is still ok as long as the login and pwd are not shared.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting topic and I think if experienced devs stopped and thought critically about the subject many would see that there are similar levels of security issues whether your front end application leverages a backend application to access their data-stores or not.

Given:

1. Having connection credentials with delete or drop privileges is always a bad idea.
2. Using straight sql commands, gives away your table structure, which typically would be bad.
3. Full table access with inserts and updates might be inadvisable for customer facing applications.

Possible good architectural design:

1. Leverage stored procedures to abstract the table structure.
2. Possibly return and consume json from the stored procedure.
3. Limit user access to only those stored procedures.
4. Have an experienced dev try to hack it.

In conclusion, direct access will probably never provide sufficient security for complex functionality, but it could be useful for simple web-apps or simple sections of larger applications. The benefit of reduced server load and faster response times could be worth it.